# How to display only contacts with phone numbers Nexus 5

Tags: contacts

I just want contacts with phone numbers to show up when I am looking them up in People. All the people I have emailed somehow ended up in My Contacts, too, but that's another issue.N\

I want to open contacts and not see Joe Schmoe from Schmoe Company on there, that I only emailed once. Any way?

Thanks :)

Comment: Click on menu//filter contacts//only show contacts with numbers. That's it.

Comment: Nope. Where do you see that?